# Cannot find suitable regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, urllib

What I'm trying to do is  to pull the HTML content and find a particular string  that I know exists

```
import urllib.request
import re

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ipchicken.com/')

data = response.read()

portregex = re.compile('Remote[\s]+Port: [\d]+')

port = portregex.findall(str(data))

print(data)
print(port)
```

Now in my case the website contains `Remote Port: 50880`, but I simply cannot come up with  suitable regex! Can anyone find my mistake?

I'm using python  3.4 on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistakenly used square brackets instead of round parentheses:

```
portregex = re.compile(r'Remote\s+Port: (\d+)')
```

This ensures that the results of `re.findall()` will contain only the matched number(s) (because `re.findall()` returns only the capturing groups' matches when those are present):

```
>>> s = "Foo Remote Port: 12345 Bar Remote    Port: 54321"
>>> portregex.findall(s)
['12345', '54321']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a raw string:

```
portregex = re.compile(r'Remote[\s]+Port: [\d]+')
```

or double backslashes:

```
portregex = re.compile('Remote[\\s]+Port: [\\d]+')
```

Note that square brackets are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an HTML parser in this case. Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ipchicken.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

print(soup.find(text=lambda x: x.startswith('Remote')).text)
```